# is it possible to select a table and join another table if the condition was met?

Tags: mysql

is it possible to select a table and join another table if the condition was met?

like `select * from table if (condition, join a table, nothing to do)`

action log table

```
id  |  user_id |  action                            |   log_time       
    |          | 0=login,1=logout,2=register_client |   
 1  |   001    |             0                      |   2014-07-20 03:10:20 
 2  |   001    |             3                      |   2014-07-20 03:10:34
 3  |   001    |             3                      |   2014-07-20 03:11:58
```

registration log table

```
id | user_id | client_id |  date_reg
1  |  001    | 186       |   2014-07-20 03:10:34
2  |  001    | 187       |   2014-07-20 03:11:58
```

the result that i got is redundant.  maybe there's is something wrong with my table. 
i need to display the first table joined with the 2nd table in which the result should 3 rows only showing 3 activites which is login and registers 2 times based on the 1st table.

Comment: im sorry i've updated my post again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is the best way to do it:
SELECT table1.id, table1.[user id], table1.type, table2.details FROM table1 LEFT JOIN
table2 ON table1.type=table2.type WHERE (conditions)

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.id, t1.type,t2.details 
from table1 t1 
left outer join table2 t2
where 
t1.id=t2.id and 
t1.type=t2.type
```

Comment: @JerahmeelAcebuche - same code should work except that add t1.userid to the select statement. select ...,t1.userid ...

Comment: i cant seem to find the answer. i'll update my post again. i'll post my real tables.

Comment: There will be more than 3 rows, to be precise there will 6 rows. It is because, for each userid in actionlog table , there are 2 userids in registration log table. If client id is the primary key in registration log, then action log should have that column. Otherwise the design won't achieve what is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for left join. You don't need a condition. It will give null when there is no corresponding line in table b.

```
select t1.*, t2.details
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.type = t2.type
```